# Arduino doesnt seem to be reading my pin states

Tags: pins, stepper

I seem to have an unbelievable thing. My code was working perfectly on one arduino, when i upload the same sketch to another one, it is behaving strangely, it seems like it is not reading any of my pin states:

The code is ment to drive a simple stepper motor with driver. depending on the state of several pins in which direction it moves or moves at all.

What is happening now is when i upload the sketch the motor starts to turn, nomatter what pinstate any of the input pins have, the motor just turns on uploading and even if i apply 5v to any of the pins, it just keeps turning the same direction.

Following the code. I hope someone could tell me what i am doing wrong, i am a newbie to programming:

```cpp
int PUL=7; //define Pulse pin
int DIR=8; //define Direction pin
//int ENA=5; //define Enable Pin
int up = 2;
int down = 3;
int limitpin=1;
int limitpinup=4;
int i=0;

int buttonupstate = 0;
int buttondownstate = 0;
int limitstate=0;
int limitstateup=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(PUL, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(up, INPUT);
  pinMode(down, INPUT);
  pinMode(limitpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(limitpinup, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonupstate = digitalRead(up);
  buttondownstate = digitalRead(down);
  limitstate = digitalRead(limitpin);
  limitstateup = digitalRead(limitpinup);
  i = 0;
  switch (limitstateup){
  case LOW:
    switch (limitstate){
    case LOW:
      if (buttondownstate==HIGH){
        do
        {
          digitalWrite(DIR,LOW);
          // digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);
          digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(20);
          digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(20);

          buttondownstate = 0;
          buttondownstate = digitalRead(down);
          limitstate == 0;
          limitstate = digitalRead(limitpin);
          limitstateup == 0;
          limitstateup = digitalRead(limitpinup);
        } while (buttondownstate == HIGH && limitstate == 0 && limitstateup == 0);
      }
      if (buttonupstate == HIGH){
        do
        {
          digitalWrite(DIR,HIGH);
          // digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);
          digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(20);
          digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(20);

          buttonupstate = 0;
          buttonupstate = digitalRead(up);
          limitstate == 0;
          limitstate = digitalRead(limitpin);
          limitstateup == 0;
          limitstateup = digitalRead(limitpinup);
        } while (buttonupstate == HIGH && limitstate == 0 && limitstateup == 0);
      }
      break;
    case HIGH:
      do{
        digitalWrite(DIR,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(20);
        digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(20);
        limitstate = 0;
        limitstate = digitalRead(limitpin);
      }while (limitstate == HIGH );
      break;
    }
    break;
  case HIGH:
    do{
      digitalWrite(DIR,LOW);
      digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(20);
      digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(20);
      limitstateup = 0;
      limitstateup = digitalRead(limitpinup);
    }while (limitstateup == HIGH );
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have pull-up or pull-down resistors on the inputs?  If they’re floating when the button isn’t pressed then they are free to read presses whenever they pick up noise.

Comment: Well to be honest nothing is connected to the input pins for the moment. If they are in low state they shouldn't do anything right?  When I uploaded to an original Arduino and connected the pins to the rest of the wiring it worked perfectly. When I upload it now to an Arduino clone it starts turning without stop.

Comment: Wenn nothing is connected to an input pin, it is not in a low state. It is floating. Google arduino floating pin. You need to connect either a pullup or a pulldown resistor. The Arduino has an internal pullup resistor, that you can activate

Comment: Actually, I just looked at the schematics of my relay board. All input pins are with pull down resistors . When connected to that the motor also just started spinning. Without stopping. It's +5v to relay to resistor to ground. So I guess that is the correct way to work for a pull down. When relay is activated it should get a high state. Correct?

Comment: We aren’t talking about your relays.  You need pull-up or pull-down on the input pin for the buttons and switches.  When nothing is connected to a pin it is in a random state sometimes reads high and sometimes low.  You need something to keep it in a defined state while the button isn’t pressed.  Google “Arduino floating input” and you should get lots of information on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all of you,

Indeed there is nothing wrong with my code. The problem is indeed in the pull-down resistors, I rebuild the connection on a breadboard and works perfectly. I will have to check my PCB that contains all relays and resistors, the problem has to be on that board, bad connection or something like that.

However I would like to state that on the Osoyoo Uno board, the whole thing worked perfectly, so there has to be something different between Osoyoo Uno board and another Arduino board.

---

Here is the schematic to my PCB board. I checked it again, but i think all the digital pins have actually pull-down resistors active.

[image: circuit schematic]

Comment: No, there doesn’t have to be anything different.  The code *appeared* to work on the other board.  But at any random time one of those inputs could have read a spurious press if it picked up the right noise.  The only difference was luck.  Floating input pins are almost never a good idea.

Comment: Post a wiring schematic.   It kind of sounds like you might not be completely understanding what we’re talking about here.  And if it seems to work now that’s no sign that it’s fixed.  If I puts are still floating then you’ve still got a problem.

Comment: By the way, the arduino has internal pull-ups.  The more normal way to arrange things is to have the button wired to read LOW when pressed and then you can use the internal pull-ups and don’t need external resistors.

Comment: I see pull downs on the relays.  But I don’t see any for the inputs to the arduino.  It’s hard to tell because the arduino isn’t in the picture but I think I see where the lines go back to the input pins and there aren’t pull-downs in those.

Comment: Or are the relays the inputs?  Usually a relay is on an output.  I’m more confused by your drawing than I was before.  How does all of this connect to arduino?

Comment: I am sorry. This was made with circuitmaker to create my own PCB for it. Actually pin number 10 on every relay leads to an input on the Arduino. You can see that in The exact middle of the schematic there are 4 terminals each lead to a digital input and are connected to a resistor and to pin 10 of every relay.

Comment: The resistors connect to pin 10 of the relay and what ground?  Is it connected to Arduino ground?

Comment: Yes all go to Arduino ground. They are grouped all together. (Also the ground from my stepper driver. Dir- and PUL-) so there is one cable for ground going from this PCB to the Arduino ground